# Use of the Neo4j GDS library for loaded graphs

Tags: neo4j, knowledge-graph, neo4j-python-driver

I'm currently working with Knowledge graphs using Neo4j algorithms. I would like to better understand how GDS library works and how I can apply it to my work using projection.

I'm new with Neo4j and I just discovered GDS library. I work with Neo4j using Python and I loaded two graphs in an instance in localhost. I have already installed gds plugin, but my problem is understanding how projection works, If it is mandatory to use gds library, how can I apply it to my existing graphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the [online documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/management-ops/graph-creation/), there are [free online GDS courses](https://graphacademy.neo4j.com/categories/data-scientist/?ref=docs&_ga=2.20282302.729521973.1709336513-1260995272.1709336513) that you may find useful for learning about GDS projections and GDS in general.